# How do I add to the existing value of a variable javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which logs the amount the user has scrolled on the page. I was hoping to add to this value if the user goes over a specific number and minus respectively. In the example below I am trying to create a function in which, if wScroll is greater then 50 change some css and then add 50 to the value of wscroll, and then else for the opposite reaction. What I am trying to do is create a page where on scroll the html gives the appearance that the each  locks into place removing the one previous/after from view.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(wScroll > 50){
      $(".header").css("height","0vh");
      $(".second").css("height","100vh");
      wScroll + 50;
    }
    else {
      $(".header").css("height","100vh");
      $(".second").css("height","10vh");
      wScroll - 50;
    }
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan this does not work to well, I have created a js fiddle as an example. please rethink your answer. https://jsfiddle.net/owbsz64g/1/

Comment: "rethink my answer" - why not "rethink your logic" ? Based on what you posted, I corrected the syntax. The question is now, how to stop the bouncing

Comment: @mplungjan how do i stop the bouncing?

Comment: I did not notice what immediately- sorry

Comment: @mplungjan so i guess you do not know how to do it?

Comment: I do not have time to investigate either